# Como exibir imagem de uma API através da URL com Angular

Tags: angular, api, rest

Estou aprendendo Angular e para isso venho desenvolvendo o tutorial Tour of Heroes da própria documentação em [Tutorial: Tuor of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt0), mas estou tentando aplicar algumas funcionalidades à mais como trazer a imagem do Herói através desta [API de Heróis](https://superheroapi.com/index.html). Eu já consegui construir uma lista com o id e nome destes herois, mas não consigo encontrar nada referente à exibir imagens de uma API. Alguém tem alguma solução prática ou indicar o que exatamente preciso estudar para realizar esta tarefa?

Segue trechos do código que já construi:

Service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Heroi } from './heroi';
import { Observable, tap } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ListaHeroisService {

private readonly API = 'https://superheroapi.com/api/5033128890082701/search/id/'

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

list() {
  return this.http.get<Heroi[]>(this.API)
  .pipe(
    tap(console.log)
  )
}

}
```

Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Heroi } from './heroi';
import { ListaHeroisService } from './lista-herois.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  herois!: Heroi[];
  

  constructor(private service: ListaHeroisService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    
 
    this.service.list().subscribe((herois:any)=>{
      this.herois = herois.results;
    })
  }

}
```

heroi.ts

```
export interface Heroi {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    image: string
}
```

Component.html

```
<ul *ngFor="let heroi of herois">
  
    <li>{{heroi.image}} - {{heroi.id}} - {{heroi.name}}</li>

</ul>
```

Resultado atual:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Oxxxiii man!!! Pra exibir a imagem com o retorno da Api, basta colocar no atributo **src** da tag `img` a propriedade que possui a url da imagem, ou seja, **`<img [src]="heroi.image.url" alt="" />`**. Fica aparecendo ali no browser `[object object]` exatamente pq heroi.image é um objeto com a propriedade url dentro, para ver a string na tela basta usar o **json pipe** assim `{{ heroi.image | json }}` ou acessar diretamente a url assim `{{ heroi.image.url }}`.

Comment: Opa!! Tentei colocar aqui <img [src]="heroi.image.url" alt="" />, mas deu erro referente "url" não existe no tipo string.
Também tentei substituir [src]="heroi.image.url" por [src]="{{ heroi.image | json }}", porém agora exibe um WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value

Comment: Ótimo que tenha acontecido isto Juliano, isso demonstra que não está pronto ainda para mexer com Angular, este framework roda em cima do **TypeScript** que como o próprio nome diz é todo baseado em tipos. Na sua interface a propriedade **image** é uma **`string`**, mas o retorno da api é um `objeto` por isso este erro que comentou. Aconselho sinceramente que pare no momento com Angular e volte os esforços para o TypeScript, depois com seus fundamentos mais claros volte para o Angular, senão vai ficar patinando nestas coisinhas bobas.

Answer (score 0):

```
export interface Heroi {
 id: string,
 name: string,
 image: { url: string }
}
```

```
<ul *ngFor="let heroi of herois">  
  <li>
    <img src="{{heroi.image.url}}" alt="">
     <p>{{ heroi.id }}</p>
     <p>{{ heroi.name }}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```